# Where is the known_hosts file for OpenSSH for Windows?

Tags: ssh, powershell

One of the servers I frequently log into via SSH has changed it's IP address. So, now I'm getting man in the middle attack warnings when I try to use SSH via Windows Powershell and OpenSSH for Windows.

On a linux machine, I would just remove the offending line from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. But, the `~/.ssh` directory seems to be empty.

Where is the known_hosts file for Powershell/OpenSSH? I've checked in `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\home\anschauung\.ssh`, but that folder is empty as well.

Comment: Don't remove it. Update the line to change the IP address from the old one to the new one to avoid opening a window for an attacker to impersonate the host.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

On windows it is usually stored in the `%USERPROFILE%\ssh` or  `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` folders. If you type  `%USERPROFILE%` into the Windows explorer address bar it will be expanded automatically. You can also try `cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\ssh"` or `cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\.ssh"` from a command prompt.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945533/is-there-a-definitive-path-for-known-hosts-in-windows

Comment: On linux there is also a system level file - /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts.  Is there an equivalent for windows?

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar issue not fixed with the user profile's known_hosts, so for anyone looking: If you have installed git, TortoiseGit, etc on Windows, the location of the overriding known_hosts file is in your git folder, e.g. Programs/Git/.ssh or Programs (x86)/Git/.ssh.

As per the error message

```
Add correct host key in /.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
```

open the known_hosts file in an editor like Sublime with admin rights, remove the corresponding entry for your server in Programs/Git/.ssh/known_hosts and the new key fingerprint will get added on the next connection.

Comment: For me: C:\Users\[My User]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh

Comment: I do not have that `ssh` directory in `C:\Program Files\Git`. This answer is perhaps outdated?